# Error : "can't access this page"

Tags: configuration, configuration-wizard

I am the only user so far who can see share point page at this time.
Have also checked user permissions, anonymous access, and also through group access and all looks right. 
Can you suggest the reason behind this problem as no one except me is able to look at the site and for others its saying Error : "can't access this page".

Comment: Can you define which components are placed on your page? Is this the default.aspx page? How about your page maintenance settings?

What did you tried by yourself already?

Comment: the page is default.aspx. I have verified the anonymous acess settings, user permission for the page and they all look fine

Comment: Please answer my first question in my comment..

Comment: Hi user9432,

Firstly I want to know whether any custom settings/special web part/coding exist in this “error” page. Because it indicates that the request is denied for default.aspx, and it seems to be related to the permission settings of the page/users.

Please let me know if there are any special permission settings or not. To troubleshoot the issue more efficiently, please find the corresponding library which is used to store the default Page, and check if any special permission are set for accessing this page/library.

Comment: Perhaps a checked out version of the page, or even of the masterpage it's using? You have to provide more info if you want us to help you.

Comment: The default.aspx should be visible to any global user that accesses it. However, when users try and access the page, they come up with this message below: Error : “can't access this page”, its a sharepoint error message

Comment: If you're not willing to answer my question, things will get difficult to help you out.

Comment: There are images, templates, events...There is no webpart, no code...permissions inherited from parent site, but there are custom and advanced permissions in the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "can't access this page" do you mean they get prompted for credentials and can't get in when providing them?

Is it a .NET error message, a SharePoint error message or a browser error message? Is that error copied and pasted exactly?

What rights are the users who can't get in supposed to have? anonymous only? contribute? Can they get into _layouts/settings if they go in to that url directly?

Comment: The default.aspx should be visible to any global user that accesses it. However, when users try and access the page, they come up with this message below: Error : “can't access this page”, its a sharepoint error message.

Comment: I tried to reset the inherited settings from parent site, didnt work

Comment: If this is meant to have anonymous access then switch anonymous off and on again at the site collection level